# Customize UITextField Clear Button Color to White Color

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, uitextfield

I want to change Color of the `UITextField`'s Clear Button, As I Know I can achieve the same with accessing the RightView Property of the TextField as Well as also I can use an Image to do the same.

But No, I want to change the colour of that button only.

Can Someone help me with the same?

The Below represents the code which I wrote to access the clear button of the UITextField.

```
for (UIView *aSubview in self.view.subviews) {
    for (UIView *bSubview in aSubview.subviews) {
        if ([bSubview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]){
            for(UIView *v in bSubview.subviews)
            {
                if([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please clarify what you want to change textfield background or button colour?

Comment: I want to change that button's colour.

Comment: are you using storyboard?

Comment: Yes, I am using a StoryBoard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From all your answers, I come to this conclusion,

```
UIButton *btnClear = [self.txtEmail valueForKey:@"_clearButton"];
UIImage *imageNormal = [btnClear imageForState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageNormal.size, NO, 0.0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGRect rect = (CGRect){ CGPointZero, imageNormal.size };
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
[imageNormal drawInRect:rect];

CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeSourceIn);
[[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

UIImage *imageTinted  = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[btnClear setImage:imageTinted forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

I am new in iOS app development.But i will try.please refer following code.

.h file:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface TextFieldTint : UITextField

-(void) setColorButtonClearHighlighted:(UIColor *)colorButtonClearHighlighted;
-(void) setColorButtonClearNormal:(UIColor *)colorButtonClearNormal;

@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "TextFieldTint.h"

@interface TextFieldTint()

@property (nonatomic,strong) UIColor *colorButtonClearHighlighted;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIColor *colorButtonClearNormal;

@property (nonatomic,strong) UIImage *imageButtonClearHighlighted;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIImage *imageButtonClearNormal;


@end

@implementation TextFieldTint


-(void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self tintButtonClear];
}

-(void) setColorButtonClearHighlighted:(UIColor *)colorButtonClearHighlighted
{
    _colorButtonClearHighlighted = colorButtonClearHighlighted;
}

-(void) setColorButtonClearNormal:(UIColor *)colorButtonClearNormal
{
    _colorButtonClearNormal = colorButtonClearNormal;
}

-(UIButton *) buttonClear
{
    for(UIView *v in self.subviews)
    {
        if([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton *buttonClear = (UIButton *) v;
            return buttonClear;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}



-(void) tintButtonClear
{
    UIButton *buttonClear = [self buttonClear];

    if(self.colorButtonClearNormal && self.colorButtonClearHighlighted && buttonClear)
    {
        if(!self.imageButtonClearHighlighted)
        {
            UIImage *imageHighlighted = [buttonClear imageForState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
            self.imageButtonClearHighlighted = [[self class] imageWithImage:imageHighlighted
                                                                  tintColor:self.colorButtonClearHighlighted];
        }
        if(!self.imageButtonClearNormal)
        {
            UIImage *imageNormal = [buttonClear imageForState:UIControlStateNormal];
            self.imageButtonClearNormal = [[self class] imageWithImage:imageNormal
                                                             tintColor:self.colorButtonClearNormal];
        }

        if(self.imageButtonClearHighlighted && self.imageButtonClearNormal)
        {
            [buttonClear setImage:self.imageButtonClearHighlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
            [buttonClear setImage:self.imageButtonClearNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}


+ (UIImage *) imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image tintColor:(UIColor *)tintColor
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, 0.0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGRect rect = (CGRect){ CGPointZero, image.size };
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
    [image drawInRect:rect];

    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeSourceIn);
    [tintColor setFill];
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    UIImage *imageTinted  = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return imageTinted;
}
@end
```